# How to add data frame contents in scala ignore null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame as shown below in scala. I got this results when I did full outer join on two different sizes of data frames.

these are the key value pairs got after executing the below Query

```
select * from TEMP1 a FULL OUTER JOIN TEMP2 b ON a.T_ROWKEY = b.N_ROWKEY
```

this below df describe the key value pair we need to add similar key values and created new data frame, if there are no similar values just keep the values as it is.

```
[2552195C312,100,2552195C312,5]
[null,null,175831A638,1]
[48061B887,1,null,null]
[null,null,171539C177,1]
[null,null,5584D2379,4]
[118732EE7792,3,null,null]
[null,null,8157FF1915,1]
[14310AA872,1000,14310AA872,7]
[148BB41539,5,148BB41539,1]
[40513SS68,1,null,null]
[null,null,199915UY72,11]
[11429401AW5,3,null,null]
[187755CD00,4,null,null]
[834413CV18,1,null,null]
[185475XS2,14,null,null]
[11716817SD8,2,null,null]
[2552998AS99,12,null,null]
[null,null,19792WS37,2]
[153054WE02,1,null,null]
[null,null,8131128ER1,7]
```

I am expecting results like

```
[2552195C312,105]
[175831A638,1]
[48061B887,1]
[171539C177,1]
[5584D2379,4]
[118732EE7792,3]
[8157FF1915,1]
[14310AA872,1007]
[148BB41539,6]
[40513SS68,1]
[199915UY72,11]
[11429401AW5,3]
[187755CD00,4]
[834413CV18,1]
[185475XS2,14]
[11716817SD8,2]
[2552998AS99,12]
[19792WS37,2]
[153054WE02,1]
[8131128ER1,7]
```

please can some body help on this. appreciated your help.

Comment: `x.map(y => y.filter(_ != null))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As you haven't stated the value column names** I am *assuming the `schema` of your `dataframe` after `outer join`* is

```
root
 |-- T_ROWKEY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- T_ROWVALUE: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- N_ROWKEY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- N_ROWVALUE: integer (nullable = true)
```

So you should be having above `schema` after you did you `outer join` as

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from TEMP1 a FULL OUTER JOIN TEMP2 b ON a.T_ROWKEY = b.N_ROWKEY").createOrReplaceTempView("JOINED")
```

Then simple `case when then else end` should give you the final result that you expect as

```
sqlContext.sql("select case when T_ROWKEY is null then `N_ROWKEY` else `T_ROWKEY` end as ROWKEY, case when T_ROWVALUE is null then 0 else `T_ROWVALUE` end  + case when N_ROWVALUE is null then 0 else `N_ROWVALUE` end as VALUE  from JOINED").show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+------------+-----+
|ROWKEY      |VALUE|
+------------+-----+
|14310AA872  |1007 |
|19792WS37   |2    |
|5584D2379   |4    |
|40513SS68   |1    |
|11716817SD8 |2    |
|11429401AW5 |3    |
|118732EE7792|3    |
|171539C177  |1    |
|187755CD00  |4    |
|8131128ER1  |7    |
|2552998AS99 |12   |
|834413CV18  |1    |
|8157FF1915  |1    |
|2552195C312 |105  |
|48061B887   |1    |
|148BB41539  |6    |
|153054WE02  |1    |
|175831A638  |1    |
|199915UY72  |11   |
|185475XS2   |14   |
+------------+-----+
```

## using api

using `when otherwise` *inbuilt function* is much easier and concise as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
joined.select(when('T_ROWKEY.isNull, 'N_ROWKEY).otherwise('T_ROWKEY).as("ROWKEY"),
              when('T_ROWVALUE.isNull, 0).otherwise('T_ROWVALUE) + when('N_ROWVALUE.isNull, 0).otherwise('N_ROWVALUE) as "VALUE")
  .show(false)
```

which should give you the above result

I hope the answer is helpful